# ksh variable value not printed

Tags: shell, ksh

I am trying to run the following script but the value of the variable `$user` does not get printed.  Can someone please explain?

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh -x

x=`tty`
at -k now <<end
        user=Bill
        echo $user >> $x
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set a variable inside heredoc. You can do this:

```
x=`tty`
user=Bill

at -k now <<end
   echo $user >> $x
end
```

Comment: This is somewhat misleading. The commands fed to `at` with a heredoc can include variable assignments.

Comment: When you use quotes e.g. `'end'` then nothing is expanded. As per `man bash`" `If any
       characters in word are quoted, the delimiter is the result of quote removal on word, and the lines in the here-document
       are not expanded.  If word is unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to  parameter  expansion,  command
       substitution,  and  arithmetic expansion.`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that variables are expanded in here docs when the end token is unquoted.

This means that the command that you pass to `at` is:

```
user=Bill
echo >> /dev/pts/4
```

If you quote the end token, i.e.

```
at -k now << 'end'
        user=Bill
        echo $user >> $x
end
```

then what you're passing to `at` is

```
user=Bill
echo $user >> $x
```

In this case `$user` is set in and expanded by `at`'s invoked shell, and will expand as you expected.

Note in this case that `$x` has to be exported, since otherwise `at` won't see it, won't include it in the environment of the invoked shell.